# In pandas DateTimeIndex how to get the week of each row since the start of the index?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Lets say I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with `DateTimeIndex` with 1 hour frequency:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
idx = pd.date_range('2000-03','2001-03', freq = '1h')
df = pd.DataFrame(index = idx, data = np.random.randn(len(idx)))
```

I would like to get the week of each row from the beginning of the `DateTimeIndex`. So the results of the first row should be zero and the last row should be 52 ( the data contains 1 year). The start of the week should be the first index in Monday of week. 
For example the result for 2000-03-01 00:00:00  (the first row) should be 0 and change to 1 when Monday starts on 2000-03-06 00:00:00

Does pandas have a function to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `diff` with `cumsum`  and get the result from `//` with every weeks' second.

```
df.index.to_series().diff().dt.total_seconds().cumsum().fillna(0)//(60*60*24*7)
```

Update

```
s=df.index.week.to_series()
s.diff().ne(0).cumsum()-1
```

Comment: This only works if the first index of the DataFrame is the first index of Monday. It however, does not works in general. If we pad the index, so it always starts from Monday it will work

Comment: @motam79 so you only need , df.index.week??

Answer (score 0):

What about explicitly converting the date index to week and then adjusting the first week to zero by subtracting the first-week number `idx[0].week`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = idx.week-idx[0].week, data = np.random.randn(len(idx)))

>>> df.head()
          0
0  0.216880
0 -0.766141
0  0.534029
0  0.238623
0  0.148866
```